# How to save user state per entity efficiently?

Tags: database, data-structures, database-design, many-to-many, entity-relationship

***TLDR: How to save a state of each user on each entity of my application avoiding cartesian-product?***

Say I have 10K entities and 10K users, and each user has a status per entity. In order to manage my users it feels like I'm going to have to save an entry per user on some cartesian table, which will have 100 million entries, and that seems irrational..

I've been thinking maybe this table could be sorted by the user's primary key, so my queries could be more efficient, but it still seems bad way to handle this situation.

Any solution would be highly appreciated, whether it's with the DB choice itself - relational or not, different ERDs or anything else

Thanks!

Comment: It kind of depends on what you want to do with the data. Also, if a user's state on a particular entity is default (which is often the case), then there's no need to store that information and your matrix becomes very sparse. We need more information about the kinds of queries you'll be running, and the nature of your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:** Based on you question, all users can have status per each entity and all of this information should be saved. You have 100 million entries with same meta data (entityID, userID, statusID). So you have Cartesian-Product here between User and Entity. There is not any ERD improvements by Data Modeling Patterns.

**Secondly:** You have 100 million entries as MAXIMUM. I think your data is not BIG enough and does not cover 3V's of BIG Data (Volume: amount of data, Velocity: speed of data in and out, Variety: range of data types and sources). You can handle it by relational DBMS's. **However**, if you have more than 100 million entries (for example 100 million entries per day or per week), you should use BIG Data technologies.

**Thirdly:** To have maximum performance in queries, you can use some In-Memory DBMS's. You have 100 million entries with 3 Long (or BigInt) IDs. So you approximately need maximum 100 * 3 * 8 MB (2400 MB=2.4 GB) memory. (I'm sure that you have Big Server to handle 10k Users with 10k Entities.)